# PHP to see if password matches and if so, submit its data

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

im new to php and learning quite fast. i have a form which allows the user to update his/her security question and also requires the user to enter his/her reference number in order to go ahead with the change.

my code for the form is as follows:

```
    <form action="securityupdated.php" method="post">

<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="secret_question">Secret Question</label></td>
    <td><span id="spryselect1">
      <select name="secret_question" id="secret_question">
        <option selected="selected">Please Select Your Secret Question</option>
        <option id="secret_question" value="What Is Your Mothers Maiden Name?">What Is Your Mothers Maiden Name</option>
        <option id="secret_question" value="What Was The Name Of Your First Pet?">What Was The Name Of Your First Pet</option>
        <option id="secret_question" value="What Was Your First Car?">What Was Your First Car</option>
        <option id="secret_question" value="What Is Your Favourite Colour?">What Is Your Favourite Colour</option>
      </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br /><label for="secret_anwser">Your Anwser</label></td>
    <td><br /><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input type="text" name="secret_anwser" id="secret_anwser" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br /><label for="password">Your Reference</label>
</td>
    <td><br />
      <span id="sprytextfield2">
      <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><br /><input name="" type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

my php script is as follows:

```
    <?php 
$secret_question = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['secret_question']);
$secret_anwser = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['secret_anwser']);

$sql= "UPDATE public SET secret_question = '$secret_question', secret_anwser = '$secret_anwser' WHERE active = 'activated' AND ni = '". $_SESSION['ni']."'";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  {
      echo '<hr /><h3 align="center">Security Question Has Been Updated</h3><hr />';

  }
?>
```

what i dont know is how to code it so that it can check if the ref entered by the user matches with my ref field in my database and if so then it should go ahead with the update and if not, it should ask the user to enter his password again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a believer in "security questions", but i suppose adding password check would be reasonable, since if someone does get to this point, he might block the real user from requesting password restoration, if thats what you are using it for. So yep, use `mysql_fetch_row` to get password (I hope it is sha1 hash?) and compare it to whatever user enters (add new password field)

HTML:

```
  <tr>
    <td><label for="password_check">Your password</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password_check" id="password_check" /></td>
  </tr>
```

And php:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM public WHERE ni = '". $_SESSION['ni']."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if(strlen($row[0])>0 && $row[0]==sha1($_POST['password_check'])){

.. your existing update code goes here
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks but if you dont mind, could you please code it for me as i dont know how to check for the match and then update the users security question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $ref_number = $_POST['reference_number'];
           $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE reference_number = 'ref_number'";
           $result = mysql_query($query);
           $output = mysql_num_rows($result);
           if($output > 0){
                //Proceed in registration or whatever you want to do here
           }else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please put your whatever again')</script>";
           }
       }

 ?>
```

Part of your form

```
 <input type='text' name='reference_number'><br />
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one ref number for everyone or just a single ref?

If every user has its own ref: 
`$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 'user_id' AND ref_number = '$Ref_Number'");`

Or if there is only one ref number:
`$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref_number = '$Ref_Number'");`

If the ref number provided equals the one in the database, then you'll get a row back.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Result) != 0)){
// your update code

} else {
// present password form
}
```

If you have only one ref-number for everyone it might be more interesting to just store that value in a variable.

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$R = mysql_fetch_array($Result);
$RealRef_number = $R['ref_number'];

if ($_POST['Ref_number'] == $RealRef_number){
  // proceed to updating
} else {
  // they were not equal..
}
```